# Swift copy attribute in initializer

Tags: swift, copy, initialization, setter, nscopying

How do I ensure objects passed to an initializer are copied, rather than only on setting those attributes later?

Using `@NSCopying`, Apple says we can achieve `copy`-property-like behavior. Per default, the attribute is only assigned though, without calling the setter which does the copying.

This is potentially dangerous as I want to rely on the property being immutable and not being modified without me knowing. (think of getting an `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString` - copying would give me an immutable instance).

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic solution, you have to copy the NSString in the init method. Note that the problem does not exist for Swift strings which are *value types*.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use @NSCopying while declaring the property.
2. From within the initialiser call self.propertyname = newValue, so that the setter gets called and copying is done.
3. To know when the value is being modified from outside of the class, implement the "set" observer (which also requires to implement get as well).

Comment: `self.propertyname = newValue` does *not* copy the object when called  *within an initializer*. I think that is what the question is about.

Comment: It does. But you have to call this after super.init , which you have check whether fine or not.

Comment: Check this one: http://swiftstub.com/203701077/. If `self.name = name` copies the string then the output should be "foo" and not "foobar".

Comment: @Tushar Attribute assignments in the constructor bypass the setter, as Martin stated.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr: It ignores the NSCopying attribute (and property observers). If you have a *computed property* then it will use the setter.

Comment: You are right @Martin & Christian. I was wrong. Thanks for pointing out and giving example through nice online tool swiftstub :)